# How to make python-telegram-bot asynchrony?

Tags: flask, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiogram

My Telegram bot receive messages from users and then do busines-logic - parse(web-scraping) data from website, using **BeautifulSoup** and also translate some data, using **googletrans**. All this takes 30 seconds for one user. When bot process this business-logic for one user, other users, who had sended messages to bot, is waiting. This is my problem. How can I solve it?

I use **aiogram** and my bot works on Flask-server. And I use method with Webhooks for receiving requests

This is past of **main.py** that receive messages:

```
@app.route('/' + bot_token, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
async def get_messages():
    print("Flag")
    print(request.json)
    message_type = list(request.json.keys())[1]

    if message_type == 'message':
        await message(bot)

    elif message_type == 'callback_query':
        await callback_query(bot, payment_token, stripe_token)

    elif message_type == 'my_chat_member':
        chat_id = request.json["my_chat_member"]["chat"]["id"]
        if request.json["my_chat_member"]["new_chat_member"]["status"] == "kicked":
            await delete_user(chat_id)

    elif message_type == 'object':
        await object(bot)

    elif message_type == 'pre_checkout_query':
        # Номер карти - 4242 4242 4242 4242
        chat_id = request.json["pre_checkout_query"]["from"]["id"]
        await add_purchase(bot, chat_id)
        pre_checkout_query_id = request.json["pre_checkout_query"]["id"]
        await bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_query_id, True)

    db.session.commit()

    return {"get messages is ok": True}
```

Maybe you need also webhook function:

```
@app.route('/')
async def webhook():
    await bot.delete_webhook()
    await bot.set_webhook(url=app_url)
    await create_stripe_webhook(app_url, payment_token)

    return '!', 200
```

This is function that performs business-logic:

```
async def top_100_films_imdb(bot, chat_id):
    url = "https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_250_найрейтинговіших_фільмів_IMDb"
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

    films = soup.find('table', class_='sortable').find('tbody').findAll('tr', limit=101)
    i = 0
    for film in films:
        if i == 0:
            i += 1
            continue

        film_place = int(film.findAll('td')[0].text)
        translator = Translator()
        try:
            film_name = film.find('i').text.replace('\n', '').replace('·', '-').replace('—', '-')
            #details = cld2.detect(film_name)
            #print(details)
            #lang = detect(film_name)
            #print(lang)
            result = translator.translate(film_name, dest='en')
        except AttributeError:
            film_name = film.findAll('td')[2].text.replace('\n', '').replace('·', '-').replace('—', '-')
            result = translator.translate(film_name, dest='en')
        uk_film_link = "https://uk.wikipedia.org" + film.findAll('td')[1].find('a').get('href')
        film_year = int(film.findAll('td')[3].text)
        film_rate = float(film.findAll('td')[4].text.replace('\n', '').replace(',', '.'))

        if result.src != 'en':
            if film_name.split('/')[0] == film_name:
                html = requests.get(uk_film_link)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
                en_film_link = soup.find('li', class_='interwiki-en').find('a').get('href')
                html = requests.get(en_film_link)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
                film_name = soup.find('th', class_='infobox-above').text.replace('·', '-').replace('—', '-')
            else:
                result = translator.translate(film_name.split('/')[0], dest='en')
                if result.src == 'en':
                    film_name = film_name.split('/')[0][:-1]
                else:
                    film_name = film_name.split('/')[1][1:]

        film_name = unidecode.unidecode(film_name)

        film = Films.query.filter_by(name=film_name, directed_at=film_year).first()
        if film is not None:
            film_availability = True
        else:
            film_availability = False

        film = TopImdbFilms.query.filter_by(name=film_name, directed_at=film_year).first()
        if film is None:
            same_place_film = TopImdbFilms.query.filter_by(place=film_place).first()
            if same_place_film is not None:
                if film_place == same_place_film.place:
                    db.session.delete(same_place_film)
                    db.session.commit()

            top_imdb_film = TopImdbFilms(film_place, film_name, film_year, film_rate, film_availability)
            db.session.add(top_imdb_film)
        else:
            film.place = film_place

        print(film_place)
        print(film_name)
        print(film_year)
        print(film_rate)
        print(film_availability)

        db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Instead of using requests, which is blocking, you should use an asyncio-aware library like aiohttp.

Comment: Are you mean example of using requests in **async def top_100_imdb_films** for web-scraping: **html = requests.get(url)**? Or you mean receiving messages in main.py: **request.json**? I think that you didn't made mistake in word requests and you mean first variant but I need to know for sure

Comment: Correct, I’m talking about the requests library. Rather than yielding control back to the event loop while it waits for a response, it blocks the event loop until it completes. There are asyncio-aware libraries, such as aiohttp, that will allow other coroutines to run while it waits.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work because when my bot, after receiving a message from user 1, for example, runs a large loop of 1000000 iterations, it will not be able to process the message from user 2 at the same time. It seems that the problem is not in parsing, but in the inability to process messages from several users at the same time. Do you know what I should fix in my code to get the result I want?

Comment: If the bottleneck is processing, not I/O, asyncio will not help you. You’ll need to use multiprocessing for that. Take a look at concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor. You can combine that with asyncio’s run_in_executor if you want asyncio to manage the I/O.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I'm afraid that I won't be able to understand this issue without an elementary example, because I'm new to this issue. I would be even more grateful if you could send me a simple example. For example, the user sends any message to the bot, the bot receives and sends an echo message after 10 seconds. Given the fact that I use webhooks, and if you can, then the aiogram library. But anywere, you already helped me more than all google)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your bot works on Webhooks, you can use Aiogram for asynchrony receiving and processing messages instead of Flask. Aiogram has special decorator for this `async_task`: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/_modules/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.html#Dispatcher.async_task.